# Отрисовка переданного Sprite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Есть два класса, назовем их txtManager и актер Obj.
txtManager создает и отдает спрайт:

```
private Sprite sprite.

public txtManager() {sprite = new Sprite;}

private void () { 
    sprite.setTexture(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pic.png")));
        sprite.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
}

public Sprite getSprite() {return sprite;}
```

Obj принимает Sprite в конструкторе и отрисовывает его.

```
Sprite sprite;

public Obj(Sprite sprite)
{
     this.sprite = sprite;
}

 @Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    sprite.draw(batch);
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что спрайт не отрисовывается. Он передает все поля, но не текстуру. Но если я сделаю так:

```
    public Obj(Sprite sprite)
{
     this.sprite = new Sprite(sprite.getTexture());
}
```

то все работает.
Вопрос: почему не работает this.sprite.setTexture(Texture)? И насколько я теряю в ресурсах, ставя "костыль" this.sprite = new Sprite(sprite.getTexture)?

p.s. заранее за что-нибудь извиняюсь.

Comment: почему работает не понятно из кода выше, но по поводу пересоздания объекта: тут зависит от того, как часто будет создаваться и уничтожаться Obj. Если часто, тогда дороговато, сборки мусора нужно всеми силами избегать в случае с играми.